# Crystal Report Requests Username and Password Over Network

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, crystal-reports

I have built a winforms application which makes extensive use of Crystal Reports to present data. It works fine on the server hosting the MSSQL DBMS but when I access the database over a network(as a client machine) I get asked for a username and password.
[image]
To circumvent this problem, I created a server login using SQL server authentication and provided that as the username and password.
It accepts this, but on the form where I'm expected to provide parameters to filter data I get another form which asks for username and password again.
I provide the same username and password for the login I created earlier but this time nothing happens.
[image]
What may be causing the problem?
Thanks.